# Displaying dates in EST

Tags: php, timezone

I have a blog on my site. Each blog-post has a comments section at the end. When the user comments, the comments show up per Central Time. However, I am looking to display them per EST. I have included the code snippet that displays the timestamp. It works fine, except that instead of EST, the time is displayed as Central.

```
$DATEFORMAT = '%b %e, %Y %I:%M %p';
```

I have used the parameters described here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

The site is hosted with GoDaddy, which falls under Central Time. I am not sure, if the fact that the site is hosted on GoDaddy server has anything to do with this. I have called and checked with GoDaddy, but they were unable to offer any advice. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```